# What is the difference between a crosscut sled and a table saw boat?

Tags: table-saw, terminology, jig

I'm a beginner in wood working and want to ensure my safety and accuracy in my projects. What is the difference between a "crosscut sled" and a "table saw boat"?

Comment: I strongly suspect that @keshlam is right in his Comment below that "boat" is a translation into English from the term used in another language. Continental European woodworking retains many archaic terms that have been undated slightly or completely in English, particularly in American English (q.v. fillister and its origin word) and when directly translated into the matching word in English they don't make sense or sound stilted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have not heard the term "table saw boat" before, but it seems they refer to the same thing.

[How to Build a Sled or Boat for a Table Saw](http://www.renovateyourworld.com/HowTo_Library/How_to_Build_a_Sled_or_Boat_for_a_Table_Saw-Carpentry_Tools-S3519.html)

[Build a sled or boat for your table saw](http://tag.wonderhowto.com/build-a-sled-or-boat-for-your-table-saw/)

Comment: I thought so but looking at this video https://www.amazon.com/ZEROPLAY-Miter-Bars-MICROJIG-Double/dp/B008O2KVR8/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&qid=1476542934&sr=8-7&keywords=crosscut+sled

Comment: I thought so, but the gentleman refers to a "boat" in the above video. He only cross cuts on the blade side and not run up the center like on sled where yoiu cut a groove in the jig.

Comment: I would still call a "drop-off sled" a kind of sled. I suspect "boat" is purely a matter of personal or local terminology, or of translation from another culture's term for this kind of jg.

Comment: I don't see a difference between a boat or a sled. Sleds can be built with a single runner on one side of the blade as well. Woodworkers have built them to crossover the blade to be able to get two runners on them, which minimizes the amount of play or slop that is demonstrated in that video. With a single runner, it is worse than with two.